# Having artifacts after changing color of an image drawn with hints

Tags: java, bufferedimage, java-2d, antialiasing

I have created a brush (BufferedImage) as following (code 1) ...

```
g.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
g.fillArc(0, 0, w, w, 0, 360);
```

Then I change the color of that image using RGBImageFilter (code 2) ...

```
public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
    int alpha = rgb & 0xFF000000;
    int newrgb = (color.getRGB() & 0x00FFFFFF) | alpha;
    return newrgb;
}
```

Now if i drag my mouse on the canvas it will draw the brush image on each mousepoint (code 3) ...

```
g2.drawImage(brush.image, trop, (int) (x - offset), (int) (y - offset));
```

The above code works fine.

But if I add a rendering hint to code 1 ...

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
g.fillArc(0, 0, w, w, 0, 360);
```

I get an artifact at the edge off the circle like below (ignore the lines above and below) ...

[image]

any way to fix this and still use antialiasing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you first create a black arc and then change the color with an ImageFilter? Why not make the arc blue in the first place?

Comment: It is just a starting color, the user can change the color to anything blue/red etc.

Comment: You can change the color of the initial brush just as easily as the filter based on user input

Comment: Initial brush can be also loaded from a png having other colors. I would need to be able to change its color as well.

Comment: @Bhupendra What is the type of your `BufferedImage`s? In your case, you should steer clear of any `*_PRE` types (because the premultiplication of alpha might affect the semi-transparent pixels in your brush).

Comment: PS: I'm also thinking using the Java2D `Stroke` API might be a better fit for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @haraldK ... im not using any pre types. I'll check out the stroke interface.